# UI Distortion on moving from viewController to tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, uiview

I have a Uiviewcontroller as a first screen which is a login screen with username and password.

after successfull login it goes to the tab bar controller which has a navigation controller as one of the views.

The problem is that on moving from viewcontroller(login screen) to tabbar controller the tab bars are not coming properly on the screen and are shifted downwards.

I have used normal view application and has inserted tabbar controller in it.

Can anyone tell the reason for this problem as well as the solution?

Thanks

Comment: I just found out 2  solutions and posting it for others' benefit        First solution:

[self.view addSubview:clubtbc.view];
            [[clubtbc view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
            [clubtbc viewWillAppear:YES];      

2nd sol:

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:clubtbc.view];
where clubtbc is the name of the tabbar controller whih is being used and the code has to be entered in the base view controller.

Comment: I added your solution as an answer. When your reputation is up you will be able to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out 2 solutions and posting it for others' benefit

First solution:

```
[self.view addSubview:clubtbc.view];
[[clubtbc view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[clubtbc viewWillAppear:YES];
```

Second solution:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:clubtbc.view];
```

where *clubtbc* is the name of the tabbar controller which is being used and the code has to be entered in the base view controller.

**Posted on behalf of @dead_soldier**